# Android Studio: Connecting to USB Device that does not have a USB Driver

Tags: android, stm32

I'm connecting to an STM32 eval board from my Android Studio app, and, while I can connect to other STM32 devices, the one I am attempting to connect to is returning the IOException message "No Driver Found".  The STM32 device connects and spits out information through a terminal just fine, I just can't get it to open on my app.  Is there any way to get the USB connection working without a driver, or am I gonna have to add a driver to my STM32 device?

**Edit**: The STM32 device currently sends over UART, I can probably just try to set up a UART connection on the Android device.  Will give a try, then update this.

**Edit 2**: Found a better way to solve my problem, just gonna get an FTDI serial converter, and not deal with solving the problem in software

Comment: The term "Android Studio app" is a bit unclear. I assume you are referring to an Android app you have developed using Android Studio. Is this correct?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Which part isn't working - does the STM32 device work fine when connected to PC? What kind of USB class does the STM32 device work in? What's the behavior on PC?

Comment: Robert: Yes.  Jacek: The STM32 device connects to the PuTTY terminal I have running on my PC, and spits out the sensor data that I'm expecting (and trying to get onto the app).  I'm pretty sure that I generalized USB to any communication that happens over a USB cable, whereas the STM32 device is really just using UART over a USB cable.  If you can't tell this is the first time I'm really using Android Studio and I'm still inexperienced with the embedded side too lol

Comment: Ok so your device sends serial data over UART (STM32 side) which then gets converted by some form of USB-to-serial converter, such as one of the FTDI devices. In this case - this is more of an Android driver-related question rather than something that affects the STM32 device in any way. The key question here is - what kind of class does that USB converter work in: some use the generic CDC profile, while FTDI chips use their proprietary protocol (their chips report VID and PID as 0 as far as I can remember). After that you should verify/ask whether this profile is supported in Android.

Comment: Found a better way to solve my issue.  Just gonna get an FTDI serial port and use that, rather than mess around with UART